# calculating limit of an exponent when base approaches 1 and exponent approaches inf

Tags: limits

I am struggling with finding the limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 11} \left(\frac{x}{11}\right)^{\frac{(x-13)\cdot (x-12)}{x-11}}$$

I've tried countless methods such as turning it into the form of $a^x \to e^{\ln(a^x)}$ and yet i didn't manage to solve it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try Lemma $1$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3537064).

Comment: Another way to make calculations easier was to instead calculate $$\lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{x}{11} + 1\right)^{\frac{(x - 1)(x - 2)}{x}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Doing some arithmetics as follows leads to the definition of $e$: $$\lim_{x \to 11} (1+\frac{x-11}{11})^{\frac{11}{x-11}\cdot(x-12)(x-13)\cdot\frac{1}{11}}=e^{\lim_{x \to 11}\frac{(x-12)(x-13)}{11}}=e^{\frac{2}{11}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Take logarithms, use l'Hôpital:

$\begin{align*}
  \lim_{x \to 11} \ln \left(\frac{x}{11}\right)^{\frac{(x - 13) (x - 12)}{x - 11}}
    &= \lim_{x \to 11} \frac{(x - 13) (x - 12)}{x - 11} \ln \frac{x}{11} \\
    &= \lim_{x \to 11} (x - 13) (x - 12) \frac{\ln x / 11}{x - 11} \\
    &= 2 \lim_{x \to 11} \frac{\ln x - \ln 11}{x - 11} \\
    &= 2 \lim_{x \to 11} \frac{1/x}{1} \\
    &= \frac{2}{11}
\end{align*}$

So:

$\begin{align*}
   \lim_{x \to 11} \left(\frac{x}{11}\right)^{\frac{(x - 13) (x - 12)}{x - 11}}
     &= e^{2/11}
\end{align*}$